# Mongo $gt, $lt query not working for NumberInt

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

Here is my screenshot,
I don't understand why sometimes value being stored as a a number and sometimes as NumberInt.

[image]

And When i am try this query for search

```
{
    "price.egglessPrice" : { '$gt' : 360, '$lt':370}
}
```

I always get the result including above screenshot. but this is not right ans. There is no price lies between 360 to 370.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind different data type of number value depends on how you are storing your value. And you have to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here for matching the results:

```
db.collection.find({
    price: {
        $elemMatch: {egglessPrice: { $gt: 360, $lt: 370}}
    }
});
```